# HTML background color

Tags: html

1.I am trying to write a html code for which the text is in red and background color is in yellow,am using the following,text is coming in red but background is not yellow,what am I missing?

2.basically I am trying to highlight some text,if there is a better way other than the highlightway,please suggese me

```
 <font face = \"Arial\" style='color:red' 'background-color:yellow'>%s</font> <br><br>"
```

Comment: The `font` element is deprecated in `HTML 4.0` and `XHTML 1.0`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A few small things - HTML attributes should be in double-quotes (with no extra whitespace around the `=`) and CSS styles should be terminated by a semicolon, like this:

```
<font face="Arial" style="color:red;background-color:yellow">%s</font>
```

Comment: Also, you may want to look at the `<blink>` tag, for a little extra visual punch... ;)

Comment: Why would you use deprecated tags?

Comment: To really set off the red text on yellow background?

Comment: Although, you are correct, I should have switched it to a span, as well, but I was trying to point out the parts that are making it actually not render. Deprecated or not, font tags work fine...

Comment: You are right that way but I was trying to make a point to use semantic `HTML`

Comment: And yes, inline styles are poor for everything but illustrative purposes. As it turns out, I actually like your answer better, which is to say, that is how it should be done, but it didn't really get to the root of some of the core concepts missing from the original snippet.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few errors in your example.

1. HTML attributes should be in double quotes.
2. Think of the style tag as a single css property with everything in one line.
3. Font tag is deprecated and could be replaced with span.
4. Best yet is to create a class in a seperate css style sheet and call on your class inside span.

HTML

```
<span class="highlight">%s</span>
```

CSS

```
.highlight
  {
    color:Red;
    background-color:Yellow;
  }
```

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks :) Seems like you beat me to it though :P
(Was my first answer to a question btw)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** `font` tag is deprecated and it's use should not encouraged.

Why not use a span tag instead

```
<span class="text">%s</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.text
  {
    color:Red;
    background-color:Yellow;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you add a class and call it

```
.text {font:arial; color:red; background:#fff;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<font face = \"Arial\" style='color:red;background-color:yellow'>%s</font> <br><br>​
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to separate the two attributes with a `;`

```
<font face="Arial" style='color:red; background-color:yellow'>This Works!</font>
```